# How to prove that what we will know isn't true isn't true?

Tags: logic, epistemology

My apologies for the convoluted question. I'm still (kinda) arguing with someone that if we have knowledge then there are facts.

One way I've argued for this, is by saying that **what we will know isn't true already isn't true**. This seems to amount to point in question, that **what we know won't turn out to be untrue**.

But I hit a mini stumbling block.

I want to show that otherwise there's no means to **know something wasn't true**, but am unsure how.

Can anyone show, ideally in the simplest terms imaginable, that:

- if we know that something *wasn't* true
- then what we *will* know isn't true already isn't true

Comment: By "what we will know isn't true already isn't true" you basically mean to say that things don't go from being true to being false? (i.e. that if they're false at some point in the future they're already false now.)

Comment: yeah, that's about it

Comment: @EliranH http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40426/are-there-facts

Comment: The characterization you just accepted from @EliranH is just not true.  It has two problems -- one is history, the other is contingency: "The average temperature of the Universe is over 1000K" was true for a while, and is now false, as far as we can tell, forevermore.  "It is safe for everyone to burn fossil fuels until we find another power source" was true -- if we had worked hard enough to find another power source, there would have been no problem with that logic.

Comment: @jobermark no that's what they mean... that democratic belief in something makes it a fact, and what was a fact at a time can later not be a fact at that time. it's not a discussion about whether the facts can change, but whether there are facts

Comment: @jobermark e.g. it can be a fact that at high noon i shot the sheriff, and then later it wasn't a fact that at high noon i shot the sheriff. the issue may be that it can't be demonstrated that there are facts, because no such argument goes through if there are no facts. i.e. they need their misquoted and misunderstood sources to explicitly state it's impossible

Comment: In that case, the answer is 'mu'.  Movements in language games can result in paradigm edits, which do shift facts.  But at any given point in time, the players accept a relatively stable set of facts.  So there are facts and they are not permanent.  "Birds are dinosaurs", "Pluto is a planet"  Facts or not?

Comment: @jobermark i think you're implausibly / needlessly confusing the issue. they don't mean that what we thought was a fact can turn out not to be, but, as i said, that the facts themselves at a time can later not be a fact at that time. i.e. not a trivial claim, an impossible one

Comment: Quantum mechanics is total overkill here, since an adequate sense of statistics or group psychology really should suffice.  But: Schrodinger's cat -- true or false?  If true, your statement is unproveable.  If false, I give up on people who hate science.

Comment: @jobermark you're going to have to say more than "schrodinger's cat true or false" i haven't studied any physics, and afaik physicists tend to agree there are facts to be discovered

Comment: OK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat true or false?  Scientists have wrestled really deeply with your question.  I avoided hauling out specialist perspectives.  But this one really is essentially your question, and it is the root of the problem.

Comment: @jobermark why not discuss this in the chatroom i set up? i'm sure that there no logical error in the presentation of it. i'm not sure what you're asking me tho

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest way to logically represent what you are saying is:

(P → ~S) → (F → ~S)

That is, if something is false in the past, it will be false in the future. This assumes that the fact expressly or implicitly specifies the temporal conditions under which it is supposed to be true, thus making its truth value timeless.

The same thing can be represented in predicate logic to express it for any fact whatsoever:

∀x[(P → ~Sx) → (F → ~Sx)]

The negation of this proposition doesn't imply any contradictions, but it does imply conclusions that most people would consider absurd. The following immediately follows from denying it:

Ǝx[F & Sx & (P → ~Sx)]

That might be translated as:

> There exists at least one future fact, which was false in the past.

If we consider that propositions are true in virtue of them being consistent with reality, the possibility of the truth value of facts changing could only mean the possibility of reality itself changing. Therefore, the denial of your proposition implies that history would not be fixed, and the following could be the case: Today, it is true that George Washington was the first president of the United States, but ten years from now that might be untrue — not because someone rewrote history but because reality itself for that period somehow underwent a change.

The denial of your proposition would also imply uncertainty with respect to everything. If one of the facts of one event could change, then who's to say that every fact couldn't also change? If reality were in a constant flux, it would be impossible to know anything at all.

Comment: thanks, this was the sorta answer i was looking for, not sure if it'd do the job tho

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: well the ending could be better demonstrated, and i was disappointed that the notation came back as not implying a contradiction. i don't need to be convinced tho

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN. Which ending? The one about uncertainty?

Comment: both of the last two paragraphs work from an intuition that may not be shared

Comment: @PédeLeão  uncertainty in every given thing does not mean utter chaos.  Ever hear of the Law of Large Numbers?  Changes do not just add up, they largely cancel one another out.  So the last sentence makes no logical sense given statistics and other observations. Quantum dynamics largely results in normal physics when there are millions of particles around, which is always.  But the action of each of them is provably impossible to know.

Comment: People want truth to be perfect and permanent, for fear that any minor flaw will make it disintegrate.  But that just doesn't happen.  Facts drift, it happens.  But in composite, whole theories and other important configurations of facts work very well without an ultimate stable basis.

Answer (score 0):

If *it* will not be true then, and *it* does not change its truth value, then *it* is not true now.

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents worth:

Knowledge isn't knowledge until the data is sorted out of the mix.  Facts then are not simply knowledge, but a function of knowledge and data.